# Why does text-align not only center text, but images, too?

Tags: css

Why does `text-align` center text *and* images?

[image]

CSS:

```
#SupplierContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    background-color: Blue;

}
#SupplierContainerContentHolder {
    background-color: Yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="SupplierContainer">
    <div id="SupplierContainerContentHolder">
        <img src="~/Shared/Suppliers/Default" alt="Suppliers: [name removed]." />
        <br />

        <p>View a complete list of our Suppliers.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what `text-align` does, post html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop),

> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned.

Since `<img>` is an inline-block element, this property applies to `<img>` as well.

Have a look at the [<img>](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) tag, where it is stated :

> The IMG element has no content; it is usually replaced inline by the image designated by the src attribute, the exception being for left or right-aligned images that are "floated" out of line.

Comment: Thank you for the informative link and answer, @Pranav. I couldn't find any reference to this on the W3 site.

Comment: I just think it's a weird naming convention that they've used for this. Why didn't they call it: `inline-block-align`? I'm not complaining, just curious. I'll accept the answer when the timer runs out.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the links. Technically, <img> is as good as text, since HTML rendering will not wait for `<img>` to load. Thus it has all the inline properties

Comment: Thanks for the update and the last comment. That explains it very well.

Answer (score 1):

Because [text-align](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop) is used to align inline elements (not just text) inside the content area of an element. If you want the image not to be affected by the "text-align", float it then:

```
#SupplierContainerContentHolder img { float:left }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place the image at left/right then you may use `float`, i.e.

```
#SupplierContainerContentHolder img{
    float:left;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5puG/).